# Laravel Eloquent генерация большого количества данных

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица `tickets` которая содержит два столбца:

> **ticket_uuid** (uuid) < primary key
>    **user_id** (int)

Необходим функционал генерации конкретного количества билетов в таблице для конкретного user_id. Как это можно реализовать? `ticket_uuid` у нас генерируется [автоматически](https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088) а `user_id` в этом случае один и тот же.
Например нужно юзеру 123 сгенерировать 500 билетов. Как мне выполнить это 500 раз?

```
DB::table('tickets')->insert(array(
        'user_id'  => '123'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях цикл помогает:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 500; $i++){
   //Добавление билета
}
```

Полезно использовать Faker:

```
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
```

Который сам сгенерирует тебе данные.
Ещё полезнее - фабрика. Вот что гласит документация:

*When testing, you may need to insert a few records into your database before executing your test. Instead of manually specifying the value of each column when you create this test data, Laravel allows you to define a default set of attributes for each of your Eloquent models using model factories. To get started, take a look at the database/factories/UserFactory.php file in your application.*

Comment: Цикл не совсем элегантное решение, да и Faker не нужен, так как это не тестовые данные которые будут неоднократно вноситься в базу

Comment: Желательно добавлять ваш краткий перевод с пояснением.

Comment: Без цикла здесь вряд ли что-то сделаешь. Или я не до конца понял твой замысел) И почему цикл не элегантное решение?)

Comment: Ок, перефразирую, нужно вставить в базу 10000 записей. 10 тысяч инсертов в цикле это нормально?

Comment: А что в этом такого?) Пример с моей практики: отправил Аяксом запрос, а ответ на приходит, Аякс всё ждёт. Смотрю на бэкэнде, пропустил итерацию, цикл бесконечный. Прошло секунд 5) И опа, точно не помню, но больше 50 000 записей в базе)

Answer (score 0):

Если суть вопроса заключалась в том, как с помощью одного запроса вставить множество записей в таблицу, то с помощью Eloquent это можно сделать так:

```
$data = array_fill(0, 500, ['user_id'  => '123']);
DB::table('tickets')->insert($data);
```